# High side switch won't turn off

Tags: microcontroller, switches, integrated-circuit

I'm using the [ISP762T](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ISP762T_20121201-DS-v01_04-en.pdf?fileId=db3a304412b407950112b428ef533ebd).

I have a 12V power source and all I want to do is switch it on and off (via microcontroller) depending if I want to power my 12V circuit or not.  That datasheet says present a logic high to turn it on.  Easy right?   Well, when I present a logic high to the input it works great - ie. 12V supplied to load.  When I present a logic low to the input (IN) it supplies around 10V to my load.  Why won't it turn off?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the ground of the microcontroller tied to the ground of the switch?

Comment: If you put a voltmeter across pins 2 and 1 when you're trying to turn off the switch, what voltage do you see?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses!  Yes, the microcontroller and the switch are tied to the same ground.  A voltage across pins 1 and 2 results in 0 volts.

Answer (score 3):

Ran across this same issue recently, a voltmeter will not provide enough load on pin 3 output to turn off(floats at 10v) with a low on pin 2. Connect a 10k resistor from pin 3(load)to ground while monitoring this with your voltmeter send a logic high to pin 2 then a low to pin 2 and you will see that the output will turn on and off as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Try a pulldown resistor on the input to your chip (the output from the MCU to the chip) and see if that helps; disconnect the MCU input and provide it with GND and High logic levels and see if it behaves as expected (if it doesn't then you know the problem is with the MCU output.)

Comment: Probably the microcontroller is driving the pin high when it's "on" but is just letting it float when it's "off."

Comment: Adding a pull-down resistor has no effect.  I also tried disconnecting the chip completely from the microcontroller.  When the input (pin 2) is shorted to ground, the output is still around 10V.  Is there any way that the switch could be damaged?